# HTML5 JS / Local database

Tags: javascript, database, html

I'm looking for a way to store data locally, no matter the type sqlite database or within a file...

I've saw webSql, file Api, localstorage...

My constraints are :

- No expiration for data, even after clearing the cache (so no localstorage)
- Read/write
- Access without a webserver (no http:// but file://)
- Manipulation with HTML5 or JS
- Optional : working with firefox

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try with the indexedDB?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB

http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb

- No expiration for data, even after clearing the cache (so no
  localstorage) => **OK (The user can delete the db, but with a different operation than clearing cache)**
- Read/write => **OK**
- Access without a webserver (no http:// but file://) => **OK**
- Manipulation with HTML5 or JS => **OK (Check the javascript API)**
- Optional : working with firefox => **OK**

Comment: thanks but on caniuse.com it's written : **IndexedDB is only available on websites with http or https URL schemes (not locally)**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you will find a solution with the given requirements. Javascript running on a browser can't directly access the local filesystem.

Even more any temp file will be removed once the user clears the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your constraints are too harsh.

The first problematic one is the **keep-after-clear-cache**.

The second is the **protocol type** (http/file). Imagine that [Cross-site scripting (**XSS**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) is applied, but (should) be better for security with the new HTML5 standard.

P.S

> Manipulation with HTML5 or JS

HTML5 regards to new JS features as well, it's not this or this